# batch ExportPackage SAS

Tags: bash, sas, sas-metadata

Batch export sas crash a few time

Good day everyone,
I am having issues with using ExportPackage.
During the export of a large folder with metadata, the script crashes after a minute and a half. This occurs specifically with a large volume of exported objects. If I export each folder separately, the script runs without any problems. I have tried increasing memory via ExportPackage.ini, but this did not produce any results. Interestingly, everything works fine through SAS MC.
Can you please advise where to look for the problem?

Comment: I suggest contacting SAS technical support.  You could also try posting to the admin section of communities.sas.com: https://communities.sas.com/t5/Administration-and-Deployment/bd-p/sas_admin .